# Windows Server 2012 gives error on installation

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012, hp-proliant

I have a HP proliant gen8 server on which i want to install windows server 2012. This is supposed to be a file server hence it has 8x1Tb physical drives in it.

The problem is after creating a logical RAID 50 drive, the installation of windows reaches a point where it gives an error of not being able to create partition on disk 0.

Please can I get any help as to what to do?!

N.B: I use the embedded intelligent provisioning to configure the array controllers before OS install...theoretically that handles the raid drivers doesn't it

Comment: Setup needs drivers for your raid controller.

Comment: @strangewalker: iambic pentameter comments are especially prone to being right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your system set up to use an MSDOS-style partition table?

This will fail in strange and wonderful ways when using any disk over 2TB in size.

For maximum safety, configure your RAID array to create two virtual disks - a smaller (100GB) one for boot and another for data.

Comment: Can you let us know the process you used for installation that caused the problem? If you used the HP provisioning CD and it created an MSDOS style partition table, that is a serious bug that needs to get fixed by HP. (though an OS and data disk is debatably still a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install Windows Server 2012 on Proliant Gen8 Hardware you should use the "intelligent provisioning" you can choose your Install Media and OS Version and a custom installation will be start.

[HP Link to intelligent provisioning](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features)

You will get this screen after press F11 on start screen.
[image]

First you should install the newest provisioning firmware and HP Proliant Firmware. If you don't use the current release of Provisioning Firmware Windows Server 2012 can't installed.

Comment: the thing is I have used intelligent provisioning to install windows server 2012 on other server hardware albeit with lesser physical storage capacity...the file server install is the first to give me such an error

Comment: Do you install the current provisioning firmware, on a Proliant Server I try to install Windows Server 2012 and it won't be run. I contact the support and they told me I should install the new provision Firmware (not similar to proliant firmware DVD) after that the installation works fine.